# Why did Nikolai Luzin almost commit suicide?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

I tried accesing the original article without much success. Can someone fill in the details ?

Comment: What is the "original article"?

Comment: [Wikipedia quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Luzin#Life) Luzin's 1906 letter to Florensky, where he hints at his reasons:"*To see the misery of people, to see the torment of life, to wend my way home from a mathematical meeting ... where, shivering in the cold, some women stand waiting in vain for dinner purchased with horror - this is an unbearable sight. It is unbearable, having seen this, to calmly study (in fact to enjoy) science.*" In 1908 letter he wrote "*I owe my interest in life to you*" see https://books.google.com/books?id=BFsnWXkqZaMC&source=gbs_navlinks_s p.338

Comment: In the past 25 some years I've read quite a bit about Luzin. Also, I have quite a bit of secondary literature dealing with Luzin and his mathematical work (at least 40 papers I would guess), and I have copies of all (maybe all but one or two?) of his papers in descriptive set theory. And yet, like @Conifold, I have no idea what you mean by "the original article".